# Vite app on AWS returns an error with loading modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, vite

I have kind of unusual error that never happened to me and couldn't find any informations about it. This error only occurs on my app deployed on AWS, after building it and running locally everything works.
This error:[image: photo on an error]

Don't really know what to do with it. I'm using typescript but had to make one file use JSX and tweak it to work with it, if that helps. Also I know that my main.tsx is present on the site but anything else is not. Don't know what else should I provide, in vs code and local build I have no errors.

Comment: Is this S3 static hosting? How are you building and deploying your code? The built code should not be having main.tsx. Should have .js.
Regarding octet-stream, this normally happens with .js assets in html file when you have a binary file which normally is a compressed file like brotli and the server is not properly returning the content-encoding: br header.